# Redis: Am I using sismembers incorrectly?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis set called `userids` with over 100,000 entries in it.

When I run

```
redis-cli smembers userids | grep 12288357681
```

it returns a value like: `1324. 12288357681`

This means that redis **found** the userid in the set.

But when I run:

```
redis-cli sismember userids 12288357681
```

it returns this: `(integer) 0`

This means that redis **DID NOT** find the userid in the set.

---

How is this possible? Am I using the sismember function incorrectly?

Comment: The ID shown when you grep is not the same you grep for.

Comment: @Theo fixed the post. The grep was done correctly by me. I typed it into stackoverflow textbox incorrectly, but i did it correctly on the linux box. The problem is still there with the redis server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the value stored in your set is `1324. 12288357681` instead of just `12288357681` ?

Check the below tests:

```
niloct@ubuntu:~$ redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> sadd userids 12288357681
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> exit
niloct@ubuntu:~$ redis-cli smembers userids | grep 12288357681
12288357681
niloct@ubuntu:~$ redis-cli sismember userids 12288357681
(integer) 1
```

Note the output of `grep`, it is different from yours.